# how to fit multivariate normal distribution with MCMC (MHadaptive)

Tags: bayesian, mcmc

I want to estimate the parameters of a multivariate normal distribution by means of MCMC sampling. The tricky part, is the covariance matrix. I know that the conventional prior choice is an inverse wishart prior (or a wishart prior for the precision matrix). However, I do not know, who to use it. When I try to estimate the parameters of the multivariate normal distribution, MHadaptive crashes because sigma is not positive definite. I also tried it with a different sampler and ended up with the same problem. Here are some other things I've tried so far:

Use the inverse wishart with cholesky parameterization and estimate the upper tri of `U`. Then `sigma=t(U)%*%U`. This doesn't lead to the positive definite problem, but it also doesn't work.

Use the precision matrix instead, which also didn't solve the problem.

Of course, I also tried estimating only the upper tri of Sigma and reconstruct Sigma, so that it is symmetric. However, it's still not positive definite.

Here is my code:

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(MHadaptive)

#data
x <- rmvnorm(100, c(20,65,-44), diag(3))

#define the log prior
logprior <- function(parvect){
    logprior <- LaplacesDemon::dinvwishart(matrix(parvect[1:9],3,3,byrow=TRUE),3, diag(3), log=TRUE) +
      dnorm(parvect[10], 0, 100000, log=TRUE) + 
      dnorm(parvect[11], 0, 100000, log=TRUE) + 
      dnorm(parvect[12], 0, 100000, log=TRUE) 
    return(logprior)
}

#define the log likelihood
LL <- function(parvect, data){
  LL <- sum(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data, parvect[10:12], matrix(parvect[1:9],3,3,byrow=TRUE), log=TRUE))

  return(LL) 
}

LL_reg <- function(parvect, data){
  LL <- LL(parvect = parvect, data=data)
  logPrior <- logprior(parvect = parvect)
  LL_reg <- LL+logPrior
  return(LL_reg)
}

#inits etc.
df_params <- data.frame(name = c( "covmat[1,1]","covmat[1,2]", "covmat[1,3]",
                                  "covmat[2,1]","covmat[2,2]","covmat[2,3]",
                                  "covmat[3,1]","covmat[3,2]","covmat[3,3]",
                                  "mean[1]", "mean[2]", "mean[3]"),
                        min = c(rep(-Inf,12)),max = c(rep(Inf,12)),init=c(as.vector(t(cov(x))), colMeans(x)))


Metro_Hastings(li_func = LL_reg, pars = df_params$init,
               par_names = df_params$name, data=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you know the likelihood and priors, why don't you try Rstan to get the estimation? Defining cov_matrix or directly put the variance-covariance matrix in the variance part of the multinormal function would restrict it as p.d.

Comment: Well, my goal here is not to fit the distribution, but to understand how to tackle such a problem in general and why this happens. I know I can easily do it in stan or jags.